# How to convert TMDB ID to IMDB ID

Tags: javascript, php, imdb

This API url: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1399?api_key=8d6d91941230817f7807d643736e8a49&append_to_response=external_ids 
outputs IMDB ID with a lot of things including this result:

```
{"imdb_id":"tt0944947","freebase_mid":"/m/0524b41","freebase_id":"/en/game_of_thrones","tvdb_id":121361,"tvrage_id":24493,"facebook_id":"GameOfThrones","instagram_id":"gameofthrones","twitter_id":"GameOfThrones"}}
```

I have this code on my file:

```
<?php
$values = info_movie_get_meta( 'ids' );



$seson = info_movie_get_meta( 'temporada' );
$epi = info_movie_get_meta( 'episodio' );

echo '<iframe src="https://videospider.in/getvideo?key=Ez99ULqORLkSi7LH&video_id='.$values.'&tmdb=1&tv=1&s='.$seson.'&e='.$epi.'"height="100%"allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
?>
```

Here,  $values = TMDB ID (I have TMDB ID need IMDB), and on my provided API URL https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/1399?.... Here 1399 is TMDB ID,... So I will extract the IMDB ID from TMDB ID with this: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/$values?.... 
Now, I have this code: 
`echo '<iframe src="https://videospider.in/getvideo?key=Ez99ULqORLkSi7LH&video_id='.$values.'.....` Here in the place of `$values`, I want to insert IMDB ID,.... I have the TMDB ID, API to Convert to TMDB to IMDB and I have IMDB ID in JS result, so how I will insert the only IMDB ID here: e`cho '<iframe src="https://videospider.in/getvideo?key=Ez99ULqORLkSi7LH&video_id=imdbID,......`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy. Just grab the link like file_get_contents or CURL, then use json_decode and you can have access to the IMDB ID as a variable.

```
$showID     =1399;
$url        ='https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'.$showID.'?api_key=8d6d91941230817f7807d643736e8a49&append_to_response=external_ids';
$content    =file_get_contents($url,false);
$json       =json_decode($content,true);
$imdbID     =$json['external_ids']['imdb_id'];
$iframeURL  ='https://videospider.in/getvideo?key=Ez99ULqORLkSi7LH&video_id='.$imdbID.'&tv=1&s='.$seson.'&e='.$epi;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is late but may help

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/external_ids?api_key=<<api_key>>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).